# How can I extract/use icons in an icontainer file?

Tags: mac, dock

I want to change dock view so I downloaded an icontainer file that should contain files to replace some in `/System/Library/CoreServices/Dock.app/Resources...`

But how to extract files from icontainer files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need specific software to open .icontainer files, e.g. [CandyBar](http://www.panic.com/candybar/).

> To use an iContainer, simply double-click it in the Finder. If it is not already running, CandyBar will launch and automatically create a new collection in your icon library. You can also import iContainers by simply dragging and dropping the iContainer directly into CandyBar's List Pane. If you would like to view the contents of an iContainer before importing it into CandyBar, and you are running Mac OS X 10.5 or later, simply select the iContainer in the Finder and press the spacebar. This will activate OS X's Quicklook feature and you can browse the icons within the iContainer quickly and easily.

Comment: yes, i thought i can do it without candy bar, does it mean that icontainer file type is a native candybar file type?

Comment: There may be other applications able to read it. On the other hand, did you check whether you can get the icons in another format? I just had a quick look at http://iconfactory.com/ and they provide different formats as well.

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried out [LiteIcon](http://freemacsoft.net/#)? It should be able to open iContainer format packages, and it is a free alternative to CandyBar.

Comment: It is not compatible with Mountain Lion.

Comment: @Spark, thanks for mentioning that. I haven't yet updgraded to Mountain Lion as of yet. Good to know.